# Remove Bootstrap switch HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-switch

I had to create refreshing (refreshing the whole chatbox with all HTML) chatbox and inside the chat box, I have a bootstrap switch. and this switch also replacing with my code.

after replacing the whole element. The bootstrap switch is stopped working. and I decided to remove the all button HTML and reAdd the switch. (if have a switch refreshing method, is good to add in my code).

And I tried this,

```
jQuery('.bootstrap-switch-wrapper').remove();
```

Seems this is not effect for anything. issue stll on there.
Any suggestions for this guys?

I'm adjusting the width of the chatbox. This is how I replaced my HTML.

```
var short_col = "<div id='short_column' class='col-lg-7 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 box-column' style='margin-bottom: 80px;'>";
var long_col  = "<div id='long_column' class='col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 box-column' style='margin-bottom: 80px;'>";
var div_close = "</div>";
var myContent = jQuery('.myContent').html();

if(showing_lbox){
    // When showing another box in same row
    jQuery('.box-column').replaceWith(short_col+myContent+div_close);
}else{
    jQuery('.box-column').replaceWith(long_col+myContent+div_close);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably because bootstrap switch adds some DOM elements in addition to the original checkboxes

Try to call `destroy` method of first and then remove the checkboxes:

```
$('.bootstrap-switch-wrapper').bootstrapSwitch('destroy');
$('.bootstrap-switch-wrapper').remove();
```

**EDIT (After updating the question)**

If the only thing you need to do is to add/remove some classes, you don't need to replace the content

Suppose you have this html:

```
<div id='some_column' class='col-lg-7 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 box-column short' style='margin-bottom: 80px;'>
```

this will change the classes:

```
var $some_column = $("#some_column");
var shortClasses = "col-lg-7 col-sm-6 short";
var longClasses = "col-lg-12 col-sm-12"
if($some_column.hasClass("short"))
    // When showing another box in same row
    $some_column.removeClass(shortClasses).addClass(longClasses);   
}else{
     $some_column.removeClass(longClasses).addClass(shortClasses); 
}
```

See [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/g5rr7xyb/2/)

Comment: thanks dude, I tried this but it's not working. I'm trying in a WordPress environment.

Comment: Please share some code of the page itself and the way you are doing refresh

Comment: yeah. question edited. thanks for letting me know the standard in here.

Answer (score 0):

Asuming the new html is created via ajax you just need to bind the bootstrapSwitch event again for the ajaxed data in the success event

```
success:function(data){
//append the data
$('.bootstrap-switch-wrapper').bootstrapSwitch();
}
```